# NumericUpDown control with DataBinding to null property value not working

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a method that sets up a numeric up down to display the value of a property in an object. That property value could be `null`.  I want the numeric up down to display zero if that's the case.  This is the code I'm using:

```
    private void NudNullBindingSetup(NumericUpDown nud, MyObject obj, string propertyName)
    {
        var b = new Binding("Value", obj, propertyName, true,
                            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        {
            NullValue = 0,
            DataSourceNullValue = null
        };
        nud.DataBindings.Add(b);
    }
```

If I put a value in the NumericUpDown, then call this binding with an object that has a `null` for the property, the control is still displaying the original value.

BTW, this method works perfectly if the object actually has a value in the property.

What have I missed?

Edit: I should note this is a `null` and not `DBNull.Value` in the object property.

Comment: Have you set the `NumericUpDown.Minimum`property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can simply set:

```
NullValue = (decimal)0,
DataSourceNullValue = null
```

And it works as expected.

**Original**

You can use [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format(v=vs.110).aspx) event to solve the problem.

> The Format event is raised when data is pushed from the data source
>   into the control. You can handle the Format event to convert
>   unformatted data from the data source into formatted data for display.

For example, here is what I wrote and works as expected in the question:

```
private void NudNullBindingSetup(NumericUpDown nud, MyObject obj, string propertyName)
{
    var b = new Binding("Value", obj, propertyName, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    b.NullValue = 0;                /*Only used in Format event*/
    b.DataSourceNullValue = null;   /*Only used in Format event*/
    b.Format += (s, e) =>
    {
        var binding = (Binding)s;
        var control = (NumericUpDown)binding.Control;

        control.Value =
            e.Value == binding.DataSourceNullValue ?
                (int)binding.NullValue : ((int?)e.Value).Value;
    };
    nud.DataBindings.Add(b);
}
```

And here is `MyObject`

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```